# How do I install Microsoft SQL Server for linux (fedora)?

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, fedora

How can I install *Microsoft SQL Server* for linux (fedora) ? I read about [Microsoft® SQL Server® ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) but haven't understood what is it. I wanted to connect to sql server for the java application operating on linux.

Comment: Not to be flippant, but why wouldn't you use PostgreSQL/*nix instead?

Comment: There is a native JDBC driver for MS SQL, using the ODBC one with Java is a needless pain in the butt.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Microsoft® SQL Server® ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) is a linux driver for native connectivity to an MSSQL Server database.

MSSQL will [only run on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx).
MSSQL 2017 onward you can install on linux server.

Comment: when MSSQL will run only on windows,what is meant by a linux driver for java connectivity to sql server database ?

Comment: @grassPro It's a MSSQL "client" that runs on linux, and connects to a MSSQL database "server" running on Windows.

Comment: -1 JDBC is for Java, ODBC is for ODBC through an ODBC connector.

Comment: @BaileyS fixed, was a mistake

Comment: @JonLin +1 for increased accuracy.

Comment: Microsoft announced SQL Server for Linux.Still closed Beta, but it is comming.

Answer (score 8):

you can install MSSQL on Linux and on Windows. Solution would be to install Windows as a virtual machine and use the ODBC driver(helps you connect to MSSQL programmatically) which you found and use in linux .

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52294.sql-server-installation-on-ubuntu.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can install SQL Server on linux, but for now, only for Red Hat and Ubuntu and is still on Beta.

The following links tell you

> How to install SQL Server in Ubuntu and Red Hat

[Install SQL Server on Red Hat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-red-hat)

[Install SQL Server on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thank you for your advice pableiros, I will consider that on the future.

Comment: Now SUSE is supported and Ubuntu is not beta any longer

Answer (score 0):

You can install mssql on Fedora. Refer to the following link: 
https://youtu.be/EZw_fWLr93Y